# matplotlib linestyle, linewidth - empty interior

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st    

x = np.linspace(0,4,10000)
f_XExact = st.gamma.pdf(x, a=2, scale=0.5)
plt.figure
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
plt.plot(x,f_XExact,color='k',linewidth=4)
```

This code plot black gamma density function with linewidth=4. Is it possible to remove the inside of this line so that only the border remains? There would then be two thin lines and between them them would be an empty space and other lines would be more visible. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for, but what about plotting a white line on top with a smaller linewidth? e.g. `plt.plot(x,f_XExact,color='w',linewidth=2)`?

Comment: It's good solution but unfortunately on the legend the line is stil all black :(